# Two different week numbers evaluated to same date

Tags: python

I'm parsing weekly time series data from a source that shows dates using a year and week number. However, when trying to use Python's `datetime.strptime` function to turn these into YYYY-MM-DD dates, two different week numbers sometimes evaluate to the same date, when I know that they should not. The weekly data is for the week ending on a Friday. For example:

```
datetime.strptime("1998-5-53", "%Y-%w-%U")
Out[43]: datetime.datetime(1999, 1, 8, 0, 0)

datetime.strptime("1999-5-01", "%Y-%w-%U")
Out[44]: datetime.datetime(1999, 1, 8, 0, 0)
```

The underlying data from the European Central Bank; an example series is [here](http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickview.do?SERIES_KEY=123.ILM.W.U2.C.A010.Z5.Z0Z).

Comment: Is the 53rd of May even a valid date?

Comment: @StoryTeller -- 53rd of May isn't a valid date -- but `%U` is the **week number in the year**.  This code is saying "give me the 5'th day of the 53'rd week of the year 1998"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1998 did not have 53 weeks; December 31st is week 52:

```
>>> datetime.strptime("1998-4-52", "%Y-%w-%U")
datetime.datetime(1998, 12, 31, 0, 0)
```

Note that the documentation for `%U` states:

> Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53]. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.

It could be that your data source sees the days preceding the first sunday as week 1 instead.

Comment: @Martijin - After looking at the source data further I think the source is indeed labeling weeks somewhat differently than expected by the underlying C strptime library.